# What is the better way to code sequence of asynchronous calls in java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

Suppose I am writing a class, which is controlling third party remote server with remote calls. Each call is asynchronous, i.e. the answer for it returns into separate function.

What is the best pattern or algorithm to wrap that remote calls?

1. Write wrapper method for each call with callback object as last parameter?
2. Each wrapper method should return "Future" object to wait for result
3. Make listener for results which should be added to an instance
4. something else?

Comment: You might be interested in reading the [netty ChannelFuture javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a lot of difference across the possible solutions you're suggesting above. I would recommend using existing classes and patterns as much as possible (e.g. you mention the `Future` class above).

One thing that may influence your solution (and that you don't mention) is whether you need to process the results in the same order as you issue the requests, and/or if you're able to process the results in parallel or whether this needs to be synchronous.

Comment: OP is talking about "sequence of asynchronous calls" which is an ordered list (at least my mental universe ^^). So I guess the first call has to be finished (returned) in order for the second call to start. Otherwise it would be a "set of asynchronouse calls" (again, my terminology).